# Slow cloth simulation baking when collider mesh starts moving

Tags: rigging, cloth-simulation, collision

I'm trying to animate a model after finally getting everything rigged, but the cloth sim slows to an imperceivable crawl the moment the collider mesh starts to move.

I'm using a hidden decimated mesh as the collider, thinking this would solve the issue but it barely makes a difference. The cloth mesh doesn't have that many faces either, as it uses a subdivision down below the cloth modifier.

When everything is stationary the bake goes at about half a second per frame, then it gets stuck on the first frame of actual motion.

I see people in tutorials using the same methods as me, getting simulations that basically run in real-time with little effort. I'm wondering if I'm missing anything, or maybe I just need to double down on what I've already tried.

Comment: Cloth simulation can take a while. Without knowing your file, not even seeing any screenshot etc. (or knowing what your hardware is capable of either) you do not provide any information other than from your expectation it should be faster, but we have no clue if that is the case.

Comment: Sorry, I was very tired when I wrote this. I'm running an intel i5 12th gen with a rtx 3060, fairly new pc. The files I'm testing on are all different but have similarly slow bake times. In each case I have a low poly mesh moving underneath a cloth mesh with the cloth mesh pinned onto the same armature as the collider mesh. I can't share images of these files as it would violate nda. I was hoping somebody could give me a general best practice for fast simulations, I think I have the hang of most points, just may have missed something in my own workflow that I can't find.